# Type inference and pattern maching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference

This doesn't type:

```
sealed trait BinOp[-InA, -InB, +Out]
case object Add extends BinOp[Int, Int, Int]

sealed trait Expression[+A]
final case class IntegerAtom(value: Int) extends Expression[Int]
final case class BinaryExp[-A, -B, +C](op: BinOp[A, B, C], lhs: Expression[A], rhs: Expression[B]) extends Expression[C]

def optimizeStep[A](x: Expression[A]): Expression[A] = x match {
  case BinaryExp(Add, IntegerAtom(a), IntegerAtom(b)) => IntegerAtom(a + b)
}
```

The most immediate thing is the usage of a case object in pattern match:

```
[error] (...) pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
[error]  found   : minimumexample.Add.type
[error]  required: minimumexample.BinOp[Any,Any,A]
```

It seems that this can be solved by introducing the eye-bleeding:

```
val AddOp = Add
```

And then:

```
case BinaryExp(AddOp, IntegerAtom(a), IntegerAtom(b)) => IntegerAtom(a + b)
```

But then:

```
[error] (...) type mismatch;
[error]  found   : minimumexample.IntegerAtom
[error]  required: minimumexample.Expression[A]
[error]     case BinaryExp(AddOp, IntegerAtom(a), IntegerAtom(b)) => IntegerAtom(a + b)
[error]                                                                         ^
```

I want to solve this as type-safely as possible, without resorting to `.asInstanceOf[]`. Thoughts?

Comment: This is a minimum (not-)working example. The compiler doesn't understand that `A` becomes `Int` after the pattern matching.

Comment: What I'm saying is, the errors I'm getting when pasting that code into the REPL are much different than the errors you're getting. The variance errors are causing the subsequent errors you're asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue with your code is a variance issue in the definition of `BinaryExp`, but that doesn't seem in scope of the question. Once you get the variance fixed, you're left with the only inconvenience that `case object` does not introduce a new type.

A typical pattern for solving this issue is to declare a `sealed trait` and then have a `case object` to extend it.

Here's an example that compiles

```
sealed trait BinOp[-InA, -InB, +Out]
sealed trait Add extends BinOp[Int, Int, Int]
case object Add extends Add

sealed trait Expression[+A]
final case class IntegerAtom(value: Int) extends Expression[Int]
final case class BinaryExp[A, B, C](op: BinOp[A, B, C], lhs: Expression[A], rhs: Expression[B]) extends Expression[C]

def optimizeStep[A](x: Expression[A]): Expression[A] = x match {
  case BinaryExp((_: Add), IntegerAtom(a), IntegerAtom(b)) => IntegerAtom(a + b)
}
```

where:

- the variance is "fixed" in a naive way (removing it)
- `Add` is now a type thanks to the `sealed trait` definition
- the match is performed with `(_: Add)`

Comment: I don't think you need `(_: Add)` if it is just a case object. It compiles in my version, anyway.

Comment: `case object` does indeed introduce a new type; you can refer to it by `Add.type`.